# ARM STR to variable in .data

Tags: assembly, arm

I am having a problem understanding why I can not initialize a variable I made in the .data section to 0. I am also linking this with GCC for printf

Example:

```
.data 
length:    .space 8   
ls: .asciz "Value: %d\n"

.text
.global main

main:   ldr x0, =ls //Set x0 to memory address of string to print
        ldr x1, =length //Loads memory address of length value as %d
        bl printf //This prints out 4264119 which I assume is what is there

        mov x0, #0 //Sets register 0 to the value 0
        ldr x1, =length //Loads the address of variable length
        str x0, [x1] //I attempt to store the value 0 in the variable length

        ldr x0, =ls
        ldr x1, =length
        bl printf //I print out length but it is still 4264119 somehow
```

Output:

```
Value: 4264119
Value: 4264119
```

If anyone could explain what I am doing wrong because I have attempted to search this but all the examples seem to do what I do.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I have solved the problem with help from @jasonharper.

The value for %d in the register x1 must be the **ACTUAL** value not the memory address.

Thus I was always printing out the address rather than the actual value.

Solution:

```
ldr x0, =ls
ldr x2, =length //Load memory address of length into x2
ldr x1, [x2]   // Load value in memory address of length into x1
bl printf      //Print out the actual value and not the memory address
```

Comment: You are printing out the address of `length`, which does not change.  If you wanted to print out its contents as a string, you'd use the `%s` format instead of `%d`.

Comment: @jasonharper when I changed the %d to %s the output became "Value: " both times so no number appeared at all

Comment: Oops, I didn't read your code closely enough, you aren't trying to store a string there.  What you need to do is actually load the value from memory (with `ldr`); there is no `printf` format for specifying the address of an integer, it wants the integer itself as a parameter.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you so much it worked, I thought you have to specify the memory address in x1 as which loads the value for %d but you have to put the actual value.